# Dynamodb query - OR condition in KeyConditionExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with `feed_guid` as the global secondary index. I want to query with a set of `feed_guid` in that table. Since `feed_guid` is not my primary keys, I can't use `getBatchItem`. When I tried the following method, I got this error:

> Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: OR

```php
    $options = array(
                'TableName' => 'feed',
                    'IndexName' => 'GuidIndex',
                    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'feed_guid = :v_guid1 or feed_guid = :v_guid2',

                    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
                        ':v_guid1' => array('S' => '8a8106e48bdbe81bf88d611f4b2104b5'),
                        ':v_guid2' => array('S' => '19cab76242a6d85717de64fe4f8acbd4')
                    ),
                    'Select' => 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
                );
                $response = $dynamodbClient->query($options);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't use `OR` condition. You should use

```
rangeAttributeName BETWEEN :rangeval1 AND :rangeval2
```

if possible or

```
feed_guid IN (:v_guid1, :v_guid2)
```

See [ExpressionAttributeValues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ExpressionAttributeValues) and [KeyConditionExpression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression)

Comment: This is not working. It shows "Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: IN" error.

Comment: Try using between. IN is used for ExpressionAttributeValues

Comment: Just read the definition first. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression

Comment: Yes. documentation says only AND supported for ranges. There is no OR. Also you could try using begins_with

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no support for either `OR` or `IN` when using `KeyConditionExpression` -- not when using the Query API, anyway.

Comment: What if instead of 2 values you have 20? How would you use between for 20 values?

Comment: @Kappacake feed_guid IN (:v_guid1, :v_guid2, :v_guid3 ...)

Comment: @user1697575 IN is not supported in KeyConditionExpression

Answer (score 8):

In order to achieve what you want here, you'll need to take the union of two separate queries.

Currently, DynamoDB's [Query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) only supports having one condition on Hash AND Range Keys in only the KeyConditionExpression because this limits the items you search and ultimately reduces cost of say a more complex query like what you've described here.

Comment: Can you please give an example "How to use union of queries?" Every where in Amazon documentation they have described theoretically.

Comment: They wrote "union of two **separate** queries" (my emphasis)
I.e. you should make two separate queries and combine the results