# Query DynamoDB with multiple begins_with clause in AppSync

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, velocity, aws-appsync, apache-velocity

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic query using AppSync and Apache Velocity Template Language (VTL).

I want to evaluate series of begins_with with "OR"

Such as:

```
{
    "operation": "Query",
    "query": {
        "expression": "pk = :pk and (begins_with(sk,:sk) or begins_with(sk, :sk1)",
        "expressionValues": {
      ":pk": { "S": "tenant:${context.args.tenantId}",
      ":sk": {"S": "my-sort-key-${context.args.evidenceId[0]}"},
      ":sk1": {"S": "my-sort-key-${context.args.evidenceId[1]}"}

   }

    }
```

But that isn't working. I've also tried using `|` instead of `or` but it hasn't worked either. I get:

> Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: "|", near: ") | begins_with" (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2;

How can I achieve this using VTL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Original answer**

you're missing a closing parenthesis after the `begins_with(sk, :sk1)`. That is, the third line should be:

```
        "expression": "pk = :pk and (begins_with(sk,:sk) or begins_with(sk, :sk1))"
```

I just ran the fixed expression and it worked as expected.

**Revised**

Actually, there are subtleties.

the `or` operator can be used in filter-expression but not in key-condition-expressions. For instance, `a = :v1 and (b = :v2 or b = :v3)` will work as long as `a` and `b` are "regular" attributes. If `a` and `b` are the table's primary key (partition key, sort key) then DDB will reject the query.

Comment: Thanks, Itay for the answer ... did you run in using a text context or did you try running it against GraphQL? I have been checking and I think this is indeed not possible.

Comment: I missed the fact the `pk` and `sk` in your table are the partition and sort key of the table. please see my revised answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I found!  Thanks for corroborating.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100038/dynamodb-query-or-condition-in-keyconditionexpression) seems that this isn't possible, as DynamoDB only accepts a single Sort key value and a single operation.

There's also no "OR" condition in the operation: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression

> If you also want to provide a condition for the sort key, it must be combined using AND with the condition for the sort key. Following is an example, using the = comparison operator for the sort key:

I am going to be restructuring the access pattern to better match my request.